# Possible to have same @+id and @string?

Tags: android, breakpoints

I'm new to Android programming. I spent a long time trying to look for a 'phantom line breakpoint' error in my code and I couldn't figure it out till I changed a string resource name.

I have an options.xml menu that contains

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
    android:title="@string/menu_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about"></item>
```

My question - I have `@+id/menu_about` *and* `@string/menu_about`. is this possible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

R.java itself is organized into some subclasses for strings, ids, drawables etc. It is possible to have two different resources with the same name as they will be members of different classes. However, you cannot have two of the same resources with the same name, like two strings named "foo" for example.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**,its possible,and you can retrieve `R.string.menu_about` and `R.id.menu_about.`

and in autogenerated `R.java` have diffrent class for that.

Comment: I think that second one is supposed to be `R.id.menu_about`  =)

Answer (score 1):

@+id/menu_about creates the item element with id "menu_about".... @string/menu_about in your code sets the title to whatever is stored in strings.xml file in your values folder (i.e. R.string.menu_about)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but most likely it was downvoted because the OP is asking if it is possible for two resources to have the same name. He is not asking what the resources do, which is what your answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can give the same name of `@+id`& `@string`.

This both were store in different class in `R.java`. Like if You declare `@+id/menu_about` this will store in `id` class. etc..